# Downloading file from S3 on mobile (Android): "Cannot open file"

Tags: android, react-native, amazon-s3, mobile, android-download-manager

I'd like to generate a signed link via S3 and then allow a mobile user to download this file. So far this is going okay (downloads with the correct name, filesize, etc).

However - when it comes to opening it (even a .png), I get the message "Cannot open file" and it doesn't turn up in the device's photos, gallery, or anything like that.

Are there some kind of headers missing? Some extra bit of set-up?

The context is a React Native app where the user requests a file, opens the URL via Linking in Chrome, Chrome downloads it, and then they can open it properly. Ideally this will work for any file types (e.g. png, jpg, docx, pdf). Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I am accessing my website in chrome on android and it downloaded the S3 file from the s3 link but when i teried to open this file it says Couldn't open file

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do this in ReactNative, you can always leverage on a native picker. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider in any case, there are tons of information to open files in ReactNative with some extensions as: https://github.com/huangzuizui/react-native-file-opener. I tried a couple of them and they work. It should do the job, check the permissions in your application as well. It can be a headers problem so you need to check all of this.